# How to calculate energy to start movement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, friction

So let me try to explain a little bit. Lets say I have a robot on wheels. I want this robot to push a block. Lets say the force to produce in order to move that block is 100N.

How much energy will I need in order to begin pushing this block?

My dilemma is, Nothing is moving, therefore no work is being produced therefore no energy... But when I push something myself, I'm obviously using energy. But how do I produce force with energy if nothing moves.

Answer (score 3):

Many students confuse the term work in physics with the conventional term of work.  Your body wastes energy when you push something, and when that something doesn't move... 100% is wasted in the biological efficiency.  **1st step:** forget the concept of how hard it would be for **you** to do it.

How much work is a table doing by holding up a 1kg weight? **zero**.  It has little to do with the fact it would be heavy and tiring for you to hold.

When you push a wall and it doesn't move, it is the same as if you leaned a filing cabinet on the wall.  nothing moves, no work.

Your question  "How much energy will I need in order to begin pushing this block?" is invalid.  The question is how much force... and that is 100N.  The energy applies in pushing it a certain distance.  The power is how fast it will move.

Comment: Just the kind of remark I was thinking on making, in particular the first paragraph!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't really confuse the terms although I understand why you bring it up. I know no work is produced, because the equation W = Fd, implies that it's force over distance. But how can you produce force without using energy?

Comment: For example. If I had a robot continuously move. It hits a block, but can not move it until I give it more power. Mathematically, how can I tell how much power I need to supply enough force to push the block

Comment: Your question is still flawed.  A very tiny amount of power, combined with the mechanical advantage of gears can in theory move an enormous block, but very slowly.

Comment: You're real question is how much power does it take to make your robot produce 100N.  That is all in the electrical and mechanical design of the robot.  You need to tell us the mechanical gearing to the wheels, and torque curve of the motor, and the resistance of the windings and then maybe we can work out the minimal power to just reach 100N.  To be clear, the "Power to produce 100N" is all the energy losses in the system, not a simple Newtonian calculation that you seem to be looking for.

Comment: "How does we apply force without using energy?"  Hang a weight on a string... lean a filing cabinet on a wall... park a car on a hill... set a coffee cup on a table... all examples of force, with no energy (no energy transfer)

Comment: None of these examples are making any effort to apply more force. If I just leaned against a cabinet, of course I'm not using any energy. I'm just using my weight. But if I'm actively pushing, using my muscles, I'm using energy to push. The same should apply to a robot pushing a block. I'm sure there is a lot that I'm missing here, but I'm not dumbfounded. If a robot moves forward, it is using chemical energy to turn the motor. If it runs into a wall, does the motor keep turning? If not, then how is it supplying force?

Comment: A stalled motor can apply force!  It's called the stall torque.  Depending on the efficiency of the windings (resistance), you will have more or less wasted energy for that torque in the stalled state.  I'm not going to explain exactly the losses in a motor, but you have to understand the energy you're looking for is the losses, the wasted energy!  You can't ask "what's the energy required to proved 100N", you just can't and I'm surprised nobody down voted your question.